# Unity Oculus Rift S - Unable to change camera's field of view

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus

In my current project, I am using the `Oculus Integration` package to interface my app with my Oculus Rift S headset and `Unity 2021.3.6f1 URP`.

While working on the project I played with the camera settings to get better visuals, and noticed that the field of view attribute always goes back to 90 (even when I set it at run time).

I went over the scripts that were imported from the Oculus package, mainly the following ones (since those are the ones used in the project): `OVRCameraRig`, `OVRManager`, `OVRHeadsetEmulator`.

But wasn't able to find anywhere in the code what is the cause. I even tried searching through all the scripts (using my IDE) for any piece of code that changes the `fieldOfView` property, and found some scripts but none of them is used in the project, and commenting those lines made no difference…

So, my question is why can't I change my camera's field of view? What caused it to constantly be set to 90?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a bad idea to change the default FOV on a VR camera - its meant to match the actual FOV of the headset and most users will experience heavy nausea if you change it more than a few degrees from the correct value. If you want to experience just how bad this feels, place a quad in front of the main camera, with unlit textured material with a texture written to from another camera (with a different fov). This simple solution will not give you stereoscopy, but should be enough to experience just how bad of and idea this is